# The composer does not see php-curl

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

Good afternoon at installation drupal 8 by use composer [screenshot](http://joxi.ru/J2bqKGEsXM5Ebm). I get the following dependency error. [screenshot error](http://joxi.ru/KAgqOz9s4O73km)

On my local machine installation was successful and without a problem. But I do not want to work on the server. At what on another user, the co-op is working like normal.

As far as I understood, he asks for the installation of a **php-curl**. But he is clever.
I was eating to reset the **php-curl** and **php-cli** and restart the server and also run from the user **root** but nothing helped.

Error:

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.5.3 requires behat/mink-selenium2-driver 1.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by behat/mink-selenium2-driver[1.3.x-dev].
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.5.4 requires behat/mink-selenium2-driver 1.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by behat/mink-selenium2-driver[1.3.x-dev].
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.5.5 requires behat/mink-selenium2-driver 1.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by behat/mink-selenium2-driver[1.3.x-dev].
    - webflo/drupal-core-require-dev 8.5.x-dev requires behat/mink-selenium2-driver 1.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by behat/mink-selenium2-driver[1.3.x-dev].
    - behat/mink-selenium2-driver 1.3.x-dev requires instaclick/php-webdriver ~1.1 -> satisfiable by instaclick/php-webdriver[1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5].
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.4.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.4.4 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.4.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.4.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.4.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.4.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.3.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.2.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.2.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.1.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for webflo/drupal-core-require-dev ~8.5.3 -> satisfiable by webflo/drupal-core-require-dev[8.5.3, 8.5.4, 8.5.5, 8.5.x-dev].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ldap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pspell.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Well, have you only modified the webserver's `php.ini` or also the one used for composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase If I take comments in cli/php.ini then I get the following error.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: That does not look good: why do you want to load a DLL file on a linux server?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes you correctly noticed that I'm trying to download the .dll file in the Linux system. But unfortunately, the php.ini file was created automatically during the installation and I did not think that it might turn out to be a configuration for another OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected this problem as follows.
1) Found the extension Curl file

```
ls /usr/lib/php/20151012/ | grep curl
- result:
curl.so
```

2) Change path in /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

```
extension=php_curl.dll --> change on
extension=curl.so
```